# Inner-Join query is returning no data on sqlserver 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

[image]

Trying to run a query which builds a list of reports that all have information stored about them from 3 different tables.

Comment: The query will not return any data if data does not satisfy the conditions in the query. You need to inspect your data. If you have brandid=11 and category with id=1, you need to check if you have data in product table which had bid =1 and cid=1 in same row in product table.

Comment: The syntax seems correct to me, You are not getting data it means that condition not satisfied, check your data in each table or you can replace inner join with left join and see the result, you will get the data from product table and if matching data not available then It will show null from other tables columns(brand & category). Also, check you have data for CELPhone in your product table. Is CELPhone spelling is correct?

Comment: SELECT p.pcode, p.pdesc, b.brand, c.category, p.price, p.qty 
FROM tblProduct 
as p inner join tblBrand 
as b on b.id = p.bid left join tblCategory 
as c on c.id = p.cid 
where p.pdesc like 'CELLPHONE'
"Result"
[pcode]0001 [pdesc]CELLPHONE [brand]Unli Wings [category]NULL [price]10000.00   [qty]2

Comment: when I do left join the caterogy result is Null

Comment: Please don't use images in future to post queries and/or data. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems fine. Just a guess check you celphone spelling 'cellphone'

or you can debug like test with you first join is it returning the data or not then next join then check with your where clause.

Comment: the "CELPHONE" spelling is Correct :(

Answer (score 1):

Please use '%' with LIKE

p.pdesc like 'CEL%'

p.pdesc like '%CEL%'